# SSH logins without a password

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I know this is a basic question for many, but how would I set up a password-less login to an SSH server? According to the Ubuntu server guide, I would just import a key into my host machine, the one from which I am connecting, to the server where the key pair was generated. The opposite happened. I can SSH from the server (Ubuntu) I would like to connect to originally, to my host computer (macOS). Even then, I'm asked for a passphrase instead of a password. What's the point of that? I followed the instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

Didn't work. I'd appreciate any insight you could give as to why this isn't working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate the key on your *local* machine and send the public key to the server. Instead, you set up your private key on your Ubuntu server and added your public key to your Mac.

First off, you're going to want to delete your server's SSH key from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, because your server shouldn't be able to SSH into your own computer.

To generate a key, simply run `ssh-keygen` on your local computer. Unless you know what you're doing, you can simply keep all options as default. Be sure to enter a key passphrase - this will protect your SSH key from being stolen by encrypting it.

> **Sysadmin Tip:** Use `ssh-keygen -b 4096` to build a longer (and more secure!) key.

Once you have your keypair generated, you'll need to upload your public key to the server you want to connect to. If you accepted the default options, your public key will be at `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Take the contents of this file and append it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.

> **Sysadmin Tip:** Do not, under any circumstances, give anyone or anything your private half of the key. It's called the *private* key for a reason.

If your server is properly configured, this will be enough to allow you to sign in using your SSH key. However, your server may not be configured properly. Ensure you have the following three lines in your server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and the lines are exactly as they appear here:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If these lines are not there, or they are not as they appear above, edit the file using `nano` or similar. Note that you will need admin (`sudo`) privileges to edit this file. If you did have to edit your config, you will need to restart your SSH service using `sudo systemctl restart ssh.service`.

> **Sysadmin Tip:** To increase security, you can disable password authentication on your server by changing `PasswordAuthentication` line to `no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Depending on your server configuration, these steps may not be the most accurate. Contact your administrator if you have one. Instructions may be different depending on your platform or configuration -- also be sure to check any relevant documentation for your platform's alternatives to commands (e.g. PuttyGen instead of `ssh-keygen` on Windows).

If this still doesn't work, you'll have to start delving into logs. Connect to your server using `ssh -vvv user@host`, and look at the server SSH logs at `/var/log/auth.log`.

Comment: Hi. This is great advice. I went through all of the steps and it still asked me for a password when I opened an SSH session from the terminal. I'm the admin for this machine. It is meant to be a simple little home server to share files, nothing more. I can look at the logs, but I have really no idea what I am looking at or for. There are no failures that I can see, though the terminal is a poor log file viewer.

Comment: @jrw You are connecting from your Mac *to* your server, correct? `ssh -vvv` should reveal the authentication log on your end and show your system attempting to use your private key. This can give you a few hints. You can always post the log here and we can help. Of course, remove anything sensitive like IP addresses or usernames/passwords.

Comment: ssh -vvv just produces a usage prompt on either end of the connection (Mac or Ubuntu). I'd post the log but the answer dialog here indicates it is too long.

Comment: Well, more accurately, it reveals a debug log that says what the system is trying. e.g. what key it's trying to read and the server responses.

Comment: This is what it produces https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlaL7g1deExIguUUfilAdLyQgroYpA

Comment: @jrw run `ssh -vvv <your remote user>@<remote host>`.

Comment: Big time output at the end, but cannot post here (too long).

Comment: Check the private key section at the bottom - it might give you some hints as to what's going on (permissions, key rejection, etc)

Comment: File: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AlaL7g1deExIguUVWb-94mz5fUqD5A

Comment: @jrw That looks like your public key was not accepted. Make sure that your remote `authorized_keys` has the *exact* contents from `id_rsa.pub` (and not `id_rsa`) in it. Otherwise, there's something else wrong that I can't really pinpoint - maybe try regenerating your private key and uploading your new public half to authorized_keys?